# Динамические кнопки в ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, c#, .net

Господа, подскажите, пожалуйста. Написал код, от которого я ожидаю, что при клике на пользовательской кнопке появляется динамическая кнопка. Далее при клике уже на динамической кнопке должен меняться текст метки. Однако этого не происходит. Почему?
Вот код

```
public partial class Default2 : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    Button b = new Button();
    private void Page_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        b.Text = "Click";
        b.ID = "Knopka";
        b.Click += delegate(object o, EventArgs E) { lblInfo.Text += "KKKYYYYYYYYY"; };

    }
    protected void Button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {       
        Page.Form.Controls.Add(b);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Как написано вот [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7713242/asp-net-dynamically-button-with-event-handler), Вам необходимо код создания и добавления на форму кнопки перенести в метод `Page_Load` или `Page_Init`.

Однако тут встает другая проблема: как понять что именно в этот `Page_Load` нужно создавать кнопку. Об этом написано [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/188584/asp-net-check-for-click-event-in-page-load)